# GIT repo connection failed in cPanel

Tags: git, cpanel

I am having issue connecting git repo to cpanel. I have added SSH keys to cPanel from git correctly. Sometime repo are connecting and sometime i am getting following issue 
Error: “/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git” reported error code “128” when it ended: fatal: could not read Password for 'https://......@bitbucket.org': No such device or address

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note: I was not able to to clone repo from codeberg.org, but I was able from gitlab.com. So, looks like codeberg is blocking ssh access, or something.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I have added SSH keys to cPanel

Then you should use an SSH URL (`git@server:user/repo`), not an HTTPS one (which starts with https://...)

See "[Guide to Git - Set Up Access to Private Repositories](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-set-up-access-to-private-repositories/)" from the CPanel Knowledge Base.

```
git clone git@example.com:MyStuff/private-repository.git
```

You [can see here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/change-the-remote-url-to-your-repository-794212774.html) a typical BitBucket SSH URL:

```
git@bitbucket.org:<account_name>/<repo_name>.git
# or
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<account_name>/<repo_name>.git
```

Note: the username for a BitBucket repo is *always* `git`.

Comment: i got another error `reported error code “128” when it ended: fatal: unable to look up git@bitbucket.org (port 9418) (Name or service not known)`

Comment: @aswzen port 9418 is the default port of the git protocol, for URL starting with `git://`. Make sure to use an actual SSH URL.

Comment: The documentation from cpanel you mentioned is deprecated. The new documentation is: 
[Guide to Git™ - Set Up Access to Private Repositories](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-set-up-access-to-private-repositories/)

Comment: @bitmover Thank you for this feedback. I have updated the URL and edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Also confirm that the repository is public, i just had this issue and figured my repository was private so it couldn't be found

Comment: why is that a problem? SSH keys have access to private repos

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "yourserverusername@yourserverdomain.com"
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.